# How to limit the speed (or flow control) of http request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, flow-control

I want to simulate end user accessing some http urls with JMeter. Is it possible to limit the connect speed for each http request like a flow control? Saying limit JMeter to fetch the response in max speed of 1M bps for each http request.

Comment: I added details to Manish answer in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following parameters in jmeter.properties should do what you trying to achieve it.

```
# Define characters per second > 0 to emulate slow connections
#httpclient.socket.http.cps=0
#httpclient.socket.https.cps=0
```

Another option is to use traffic shaper, tc if you are on linux.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Manish answer:

Note up to 2.9 version all combinations did not work :

- HttpCient31 : Http & HTTPS OK
- HttpCient4 : Http only
- Java : KO

See:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55455

It is fixed now and will be available in next 2.10 version or available now (21 august 2013) in nightly builds:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Answer (score 2):

Where to define the network bandwidth?

In jmeter.properties we can read:

## Define characters per second > 0 to emulate slow connections

## httpclient.socket.http.cps=0

## httpclient.socket.https.cps=0

How to modify network bandwith?

cps values are calculated with this formula :

cps = (target bandwidth in kbps * 1024) / 8

Network bandwidth   cps value

Mobile data GPRS : 171 kbit/s   21888

Mobile data EDGE : 384 kbit/s   49152

Mobile data HSPA : 14,4 Mbp/s   1843200

Mobile data HSPA+ : 21 Mbp/s    2688000

Mobile data DC-HSPA+ : 42 Mbps  5376000

Mobile data LTE : 150 Mbp/s 19200000

WIFI 802.11a/g : 54 Mbit/s  6912000

WIFI 802.11n : 600 Mbit/s   76800000

Ethernet LAN ; 10 Mbit/s    1280000

Fast Ethernet : 100 Mbit/s  12800000

Gigabit Ethernet : 1 Gbit/s 128000000

10 Gigabit Ethernet : 10 Gbit/s 1280000000

100 Gigabit Ethernet : 100 Gbit/s   12800000000

WAN modems V.92 modems : 56 kbit/s  7168

ADSL : 8 Mbit/s 1024000

ADSL2 : 12 Mbit/s   1536000

ADSL2+ : 24 Mbit/s  3072000

Configuration summary:

1. Ensure you use HttpClient 3.1 or HttpClient 4 implementations
2. Configure bandwidth by defining the 2 properties above in /bin/user.properties

source :

https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks